# importing .txt files to postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 .txt files in the following form:

1.

```
109.169.248.247 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
```

2.

```
 081116 203518 143 INFO dfs.DataNode$DataXceiver: Receiving block blk_-1608999687919862906 src: /10.250.19.102:54106 dest: /10.250.19.102:50010
```

3.

```
081116 203521 19 INFO dfs.FSNamesystem: BLOCK* ask 10.250.14.224:50010 to replicate blk_-1608999687919862906 to datanode(s) 10.251.215.16:50010 10.251.71.193:50010
```

How do i import them into tables? manually is not an option since the size of .txt is over 1 MB each.

Comment: what are the delimiters?

Comment: This is exactly how i received the .txt file for example, the 1st file is supposed to be in the form of clientIP, userID, timestamp, HTTP method, resource requested, HTTP response status, response size, referer, user agent string.

Comment: Ouch -- I think you are probably better off making a delimited version of the files (using a scripting language with regular expressions, like Perl/Python/Bash/YouNameIt), then importing it (either as a CSV, or as a series of constructed `INSERT` or statements)